# Fetching from title attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a tooltip which on object rollover fetches information from its title attribute and displays it.

I would like to display three different thigs: Name, address and image. How can i achieve that since there is only one title attribute allowed?

I could save it as `title="John, Address 55, image.jpg"` but then dont know how to use every single separate piece of information (name, address, link) with jquery.

If there are any better solutions, please suggest.

Comment: HTML5 [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) !

Comment: It would be better to use `JSON`. Else you can use data attribute mentioned in by @adeno

Answer (score 2):

Using HTML5 data attratutes

HTML

```
<div data-name="John"
  data-location="Address 55"
  data-image="image.jpg">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var el = $('div')
el.data('name')
el.data('location')
el.data('image')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

***HTML CODE***

```
<div>
    <div title="John,Address 55,image.jpg" class="facedata"> fdgfdsg
    </div>
</div>
```

***JS CODE***

```
var s, arr=new Array();
s= $('.facedata').attr('title');
arr=s.split(",");
for(var a=0; a<arr.length;a++){
  console.log(arr[a]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hCMJ5/29/

Comment: @Jamaica Bob is the code working? please inform if modification needed.

Comment: What is faster? Split or JSON method?

Answer (score 0):

put your title like this :

```
title='{"name":"John","age":"55","img":"image.jpg"}'

then use this is js code

var myString = $("#myObject").attr('title').
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(myString);

alert(obj.name);
alert(obj.age);
alert(obj.img)
```

Obviously do not user alert in practice but use these values in your custom tooltip

Comment: What is faster? Split or JSON method?

Comment: split is faster but json returns an associated object

Answer (score 0):

Something like tool tips.

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="name, address, image">tool tip</a>
<div id="tooltip-content">
    <span class="name field"></span>
    <span class="address field"></span>
    <span class="image field"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready( function (){ 
    jQuery(".tooltip").hover(function(){
        var str = jQuery(this).attr("title").split(",");
        jQuery.each(str, function(index, value){
            value = value.trim();
            jQuery(".field:eq("+index+")").text(value);
        });
        jQuery("#tooltip-content").fadeIn();
    }, function(){
        jQuery("#tooltip-content").fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```